# Raster images Correlation coefficient as a raster image

Tags: statistics, gis, raster, correlation, t-test

I have two raster images. One is the yearly mean temperature and another is the yearly mean land surface temperature. I want to create an image which represents the correlation coefficient of these two raster images. I give an example image. I want this type of image. Now which software can help me to create this image and also the steps?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm1Cj.png)

Now which software can help me to create this image and also the steps? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbqw9.png)